# error when compiling compass / bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

i'm running ruby 2.0.0x64 on windows

i do

```
gem update --system
gem install compass
gem install breakpoint
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

and then i create a project :

```
compass create -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
```

and then put

```
require 'breakpoint'
```

in the config.rb and compile once, It's ALL GOOD
but when i compile an other time and i got this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["146"] of C: No such file or directory - C:/Users/flairon/Desktop/test/bootstrap/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a
7d8997/C%058%092Ruby200-x64%092lib%092ruby%092gems%0922.0.0%092gems%092bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1%092assets%092stylesheets%092bootstrap%092_component-anim
ations.scssc20140817-3940-158dqg2
```

Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

so i use --trace and got this:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["146"] of C: No such file or directory - C:/Users/flairon/Desktop/test/bootstrap/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a
7d8997/C%058%092Ruby200-x64%092lib%092ruby%092gems%0922.0.0%092gems%092bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1%092assets%092stylesheets%092bootstrap%092_component-anim
ations.scssc20140817-5820-orclq9

C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:146:in `open'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:146:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:136:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/util.rb:1210:in `new'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/util.rb:1210:in `atomic_create_and_write_file'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb:39:in `_store'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/cache_stores/base.rb:51:in `store'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `block in store'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `store'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/engine.rb:420:in `_to_tree'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/engine.rb:305:in `to_tree'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:178:in `block in compute_dependencies'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:192:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:193:in `block in each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:193:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:193:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:174:in `grep'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:174:in `compute_dependencies'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:149:in `dependencies'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:125:in `dependencies_stale?'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:166:in `block in dependency_updated?'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:81:in `call'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:81:in `stylesheet_modified_since?'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:69:in `stylesheet_needs_update?'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:210:in `block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:40:in `compile!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:49:in `perform'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/bin/compass:44:in `call'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Is it normal, or not and how to correct this error.
Thank's!

EDIT: 24/08/14

in: C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap. The file _component-animations.scss is in it, and it content:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  @include transition(opacity .15s linear);
  &.in {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.collapse {
  display: none;

  &.in      { display: block; }
  // [converter] extracted tr&.in to tr.collapse.in
  // [converter] extracted tbody&.in to tbody.collapse.in
}

tr.collapse.in    { display: table-row; }

tbody.collapse.in { display: table-row-group; }

.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include transition(height .35s ease);
}
```

Comment: It will be good if you post the content of ````C:/Users/flairon/Desktop/test/bootstrap/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a
7d8997/C%058%092Ruby200-x64%092lib%092ruby%092gems%0922.0.0%092gems%092bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1%092assets%092stylesheets%092bootstrap%092_component-anim
ations.scss```` somewhere

Comment: In C:/Users/flairon/Desktop/test/bootstrap/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41‌​567cc2a there is no file named _component-anim ations.scss

Comment: Nope, i work on a debian vm now..